# Optimising an async web crawler written in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, optimization, python-asyncio

I have created this web crawler as part of an assignment, I am quite new to python and asyncio. I will share my code below but I would like to know if this is the most optimal way to design the crawler. I try to leverage TaskGroup class to schedule coroutines and use concurent programming to do CPU intensive operations (like parsing HTML).

Do you know how this could be optimised further?

```
import asyncio
import logging
import time

import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import click

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


ANCHOR_TAG = 'a'
HREF = 'href'

def time_profile(func):
    async def function_timer(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        value = await func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = time.time()
        _logger.info(f"Crawling completed successfully,  it took {end - start} seconds")
    return value
return function_timer

class Crawler():
    def __init__(self, root_url) -> None:
        self.root_url = root_url
        self.expanded = {root_url}

    @time_profile
    async def resolve(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session, asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:    
            tg.create_task(self._fetch(tg, session, self.root_url))

    async def _fetch(self, tg, session, url):
        _logger.debug(f"Fetching HTML for {url}")
        try:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                # Retrieving HTML is I/O intensive operation, hence awaiting for it
                html = await response.text()

                # Parsing is CPU Intensive operation, scheduling it to a seperate thread
                tg.create_task(asyncio.to_thread(self._parse_html, html, url, tg, session))
        except Exception as e:
            # swallow exception to allow other tasks to be executed
            _logger.error(e)

    def _parse_html(self, html, root, tg, session):
        _logger.debug(f"Parsing html blob for url {root}")
        parser = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
        for tag in parser.find_all(ANCHOR_TAG, href=True):
            url = urlparse(tag.attrs[HREF])
            if not url.netloc or url.netloc == self.root_url:
                nxt = f"{self.root_url}/{url.path}"
                if nxt not in self.expanded:
                    self.expanded.add(nxt)
                    click.echo(nxt)
                    tg.create_task(self._fetch(tg, session, nxt))
```